# problems with sending email using foreign key email

Tags: python, django

I need to send an email when I pay in the Mensalista table, but with this code I can not get the email that appears through the foreign key in the Veiculo field
and even when he was sending before, in the body of the email the code
"def total_mes_pagar" appeared like this:

models.py

```
class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="2018")
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.modelo) + ' - ' + str(self.placa)

class Mensalista(models.Model):
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        blank=False)
    inicio = models.DateField(("Início"), default=datetime.date.today)
    validade = models.DateField(("Validade"), blank=False, )
    valor_mes = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)


@property
    def email(self):
        return self.pessoa.email

    def mensal(self):
        return math.ceil((self.validade - self.inicio).total_seconds() / 
            86400)

    def total_mes(self):
        return math.ceil(self.mensal() // 30)

    def total_mes_pagar(self):
        return self.valor_mes * self.total_mes()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.veiculo) + ' - ' + str(self.inicio)

    def send_email(self):
        if self.pago == 'Sim':
            assunto = 'Comprovante pagamento Estacione Aqui 24 Horas'
            mensagem = 'Obrigado por utilizar o Estacione Aqui 24 horas. 
                Ativação do estacionamento dia :  ' + str(self.inicio) + 
                    'Com validade até o dia   ' + str(
                         self.validade) + '  Confirmamos o pagamento do 
                              valor de: ' + str(self.total_mes_pagar) + '   
                                  E aguardamos seu retorno '
            recipient_list = [self.email]

            send_mail(
                assunto,
                mensagem,
                'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
                [recipient_list],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? It's unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your property is wrong as `Mensalista` doesn't have `pessoa` attr:
Should be:

```
@property
def email(self):
    return self.veiculo.proprietario.email
```

Comment: perfect my friends